# How to set logon hours to logon denied in ActiveDirectory Using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I would need help with the powershell command for setting logonhours property to login denied in AD.

[Screen Capture for Logon Hours Window in AD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drlwj.png)

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: You can get them using `Get-AdUser -Filter * -Properties LogonHours` (its a byte array). So, I suppose you can set them as well using `Set-AdUser` but I've never done it before...

Comment: Stackoverflow is a programmer's Q&A site, not a "here's my requirement, can someone write the code for me" site. What does your code look like so far?

Answer (score 0):

So best to make template user, then pull the values from that. I wrote this that will give you what you need:

```
$hours = get-aduser TempUserYouCreatedToGetItSetTheWayYouWanted -property logonhours | select -ExpandProperty logonhours
$Counter = 0
$HoursString = "[byte[]]`$hours = @("
foreach ($h in $hours) {
    if ($Counter -gt 0) { 
    $HoursString = $HoursString + ","
    }
    $HoursString = $HoursString + "$($h)"
    $Counter++
}
$HoursString = $HoursString + ")"
write-output $HoursString
```

The output will look like this:

```
[byte[]]$hours = @(255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,128,255,255,128,255,255,128,255,255,128,255,255,255)
```

Which can be used by set-adusers like this:

```
set-aduser -identity whoeverYouWant -replace @{logonhours = $hours}
```

Comment: The above command set-aduser -identity whoeverYouWant -replace @{logonhours = $hours} did not work it gives me an error Set-ADUser : The request is not supported, logon status has to be denied as shown in the screenshot attached

Comment: @AnilkumarTkd It worked perfectly for me. 

I setted the "$hours" variable using the output of the script and then setted the logon hours with the "set-aduser" cmdlet:

[byte[]]$hours = @(0,0,0,224,255,63,224,255,63,224,255,63,224,255,63,224,255,63,0,0,0)

set-aduser -identity user -Replace @{logonhours = $hours}